# DevExpress.XtraEditors.DateEdit set datetime value

Tags: c#, datetime, devexpress

I need to assign DateTime value to DevExpress.XtraEditors.DateEdit. Are there any ideas to write such datetime values as: days, years, months, hours and so on? 
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are talking about display formatting and mask "days, years, months, hours ..."
If so, you can use the followihg code:

```
// 31, 2012, December, 23:59:59
dateEdit1.EditValue = new System.DateTime(2012, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59);
dateEdit1.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "dd, yyyy, MMMM, HH:mm:ss";
dateEdit1.Properties.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = true;
```

Related help article: [Mask Type: Date-time](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1497)